# header('Location:') not working

Tags: php

So, two questions!

1. When using header('location: newHome.php') Does that file need to be in the same directory?

   I was going to have my signOut.php in the main directory, and be able to sign out of the website from any page.. example.com/example/example.example.html
2. My code just returns a error page at example.com/signOut.php The signOut.php is in the same directory as where I am testing it from..

**example.com/example.php**

```
<li><a href="signOut.php"><strong>Sign Out</strong>
```

**example.com/signOut.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header('Location: http://www.example.com/newHome.html');
?>
```

Comment: `Location` need to be `location`

Comment: What error message is coming exactly?

Comment: Should be something wrong with `$_SESSION = array();`. Learn how to use it from the start at http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: @AmitGupta File not found (error 404)

Comment: set/define constant variable of your website URL like SITE_URL to use anywhere in the website.

Comment: like  define(SITE_URL,"http://www.example.com");

Comment: then use it like <li><a href="<?php echo SITE_URL ?>/signOut.php"><strong>Sign Out</strong>

Comment: And you can define this constant variable in any of your common file used in your website like connection.php

Comment: @AlivetoDie I don't think so, `Location` is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1) Answer to your 1st Question (When using header('location: newHome.php') Does that file need to be in the same directory?)*

If you will not give any path then **Yes** it must be in the same directory.

Though, you need to define constant for your website URL like below:

```
define(SITE_URL,"http://www.example.com/");
```

And then use it anywhere in your website like below:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>signOut.php"><strong>Sign Out</strong>
```

Follow below link to learn more about Constants :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

*2) Answer to your 2nd Question (My code just returns a error page at example.com/signOut.php)*

This is happening because your path is not correct. Manually correct the path or follow my first answer and define constant to correct it.

I don't think there is any issue with Headers as error you are saying with 404 Not found.

Comment: It didn't work I defined SITE_URL in the example.com/example.php and signOut.php, define(SITE_URL,"http://www.example.com/") same problem

Comment: Where you define it? It must define in some common page that you will include in all your pages.

Comment: Is there any common file you are using or create one like constants.php and include this file in beginning of all your files. I am telling you standard approach. Once you start using it, you will get no issue with paths later on.

Comment: I understand how this is helpful the define part, but as far as I could tell since the two pages are in the same directory, the above code I posted as the question should have worked? It takes me to the signOut.php page, but that page just throws a error file not found error 404 and doesn't redirect me...

Comment: Please check your file name is signOut, file names are case sensitive so make sure all characters are same.

Comment: No include files, haven't had any use for any Constants yet.. although site_url is a pretty nifty approach... I just defined SITE_URL on the two pages I am testing it on, still not working using that approach however..

Comment: Ok check file name first if exactly same, I can help you with all possibilities and resolve your issue for sure.

Comment: signout.php, I label all my files by smallThanUpper, somehow I missed the capital O..... The joys of coding....

Comment: Yeh I thought so.. its nice... Please accept my answer.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

either, in the same folder

```
header('location: newHome.php');
```

or, not in the same folder

```
header('location: path/to/newHome.php');
```

or, a full URL

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/newHome.html');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ob_start();
header('Location: http://www.example.com/newHome.html');
```

just use **ob_start();** before header it will help

Comment: `ob_start();` is not the key.